# Storyboard: Perform a segue on condition

Tags: ios, storyboard, hierarchy

I have this set up in my storyboard:

ViewController
LogInViewController
WebViewController

I have modal segues from VC to LIVC and WVC. In VC's viewDidAppear I run some code to determine if LIVC needs to be displayed, if not then I display WVC. I do this by calling this method:

```
- (void) pushToMainView : (NSString*) strSegue  {

    if (self.didLoad) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:strSegue sender:self];
    }

}
```

If the LIVC presented, what I need to happen is, once the login is validated display the WVC. However I get an error:

```
Attempt to present <WebViewController: 0x7a45ef90> on <ViewController: 0x78694bd0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I'm thinking this is because the current stack order is in VC hierarchy LIVC is next. How would I be able to remove LIVC and bring in WVC.

Comment: Are the controllers embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: No, there's no nav controller.

Comment: What is the segue's type ??

Comment: They are modal. I resolved it. Since my hierarchy is VC-->some vc I can use dismissViewControllerAnimated. This sets the viewcontroller property presentedViewController to nil and allows me to then present a new vc. I was getting stuck because a VC can have only one presentedVC and I wasn't removing it before I tried to present another one.